# Swift: sort array by more than 2 possible values

Tags: swift, sorting

I have an object like this:

```
enum State {
    case starting
    case inProgress
    case done
}

struct MyData {
    var state: State
}

var array: [MyData]
```

Now I want to sort `array` to have the `starting` items first, then the `inProgress` ones and then the `done` ones. How can I do so?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (playground code)

```
enum State: Int {
    case starting
    case inProgress
    case done
}

struct MyData {
    var state: State
}

let myData1 = MyData(state: .inProgress)
let myData2 = MyData(state: .done)
let myData3 = MyData(state: .starting)
let myData4 = MyData(state: .starting)
let myData5 = MyData(state: .inProgress)

var array = [myData1, myData2, myData3, myData4, myData5]
var sortedArray = array.sorted() { $0.state.rawValue < $1.state.rawValue }

print(sortedArray)
```

This approach uses the rawValue int of the enum to sort the items. I get the expected output from the print statement above.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way of doing it.

Make `State` conform to `Comparable`

```
enum State: Int, Comparable {

    case starting = 0
    case inProgress = 1
    case done = 2

    static func <(lhs: State, rhs: State) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}
```

Sort it using `state`

```
let elms: [MyData] = ...
let sorted = elms.sorted { $0.state < $1.state }
```